# MainActivity is not started from startActivity(i) anymore although no changes in code were made

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, dependencies

A few days ago my app stopped working on several devices. The code has not been touched for at least a year (ie: no recent changes made). It starts with a SplashScreenActivity from which some data is downloaded from an sql database, which works just fine. After that this data is `putExtra` to an Intent which used to start MainActivity - and that's where the app suddenly closes. From debugging I know that the Intent is still created correctly but in MainActivity "`onCreate`" is not called. I do not know what's in between and why it stopped working, maybe something concerning dependencies? Any ideas?

below is the code of SplashScreen and the onCreate method of MainActivity, and the `build.gradle` (app) in which I made some changes trying to solve the problem already (deprecated compile changed to implementation and versions of dependencies and `sdkVersion`). That didn't fix it.

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myname.myapp"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 14
            versionName "1.51"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            targetCompatibility = 1.8
            sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

SplashScreenActivity:

```
    package com.myname.myapp;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    
        private String mAccessCode; // --> DatabaseID
        public String getmAccessCode() {
            return mAccessCode;
        }
        public void setmAccessCode(String mAccessCode) {
            this.mAccessCode = mAccessCode;
        }
    
        private String getPrefsString(String prefName) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            return sharedPreferences.getString(prefName, getString(R.string.default_access_code));
    
        }
    
        public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
        }
    
        ArrayList<String> strResult = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            TextView textViewVersionName = findViewById(R.id.textViewVersionName);
            textViewVersionName.setText("Version " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
    
            setmAccessCode(getPrefsString("AccessCode"));
    
            if (isOnline()) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_users), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
                    strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_ridesByDate), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
                    strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_ridesByDriverID), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
                    strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_passengersByDate), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("tableContents", strResult);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

            }, 1500);
    
            } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.connection_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent i = getIntent();
            ArrayList<String> tableContents = i.getStringArrayListExtra("tableContents");
            initActivity(tableContents);
    
        }
```

If there is anything else I should post, please comment. Thank you for your help!

Edit: Here's the log

```
2019-09-17 10:25:35.127 13305-13305/? I/name.myap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-09-17 10:25:35.151 13305-13305/? E/name.myap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-09-17 10:25:35.153 13305-13305/? W/name.myap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-09-17 10:25:35.230 13305-13305/? I/name.myap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-09-17 10:25:36.608 13305-13305/com.myname.myapp I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-09-17 10:25:36.608 13305-13305/com.myname.myapp I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-09-17 10:25:36.608 13305-13305/com.myname.myapp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-09-17 10:25:36.626 13305-13305/com.myname.myapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2019-09-17 10:25:36.644 13305-13338/com.myname.myapp D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2019-09-17 10:25:36.644 13305-13338/com.myname.myapp W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2019-09-17 10:25:36.634 13305-13305/com.myname.myapp W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:70): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6782 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
2019-09-17 10:25:36.703 13305-13338/com.myname.myapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2019-09-17 10:25:36.710 13305-13338/com.myname.myapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2019-09-17 10:25:36.719 13305-13338/com.myname.myapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2019-09-17 10:25:36.803 13305-13341/com.myname.myapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-09-17 10:25:36.831 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-09-17 10:25:36.862 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2019-09-17 10:25:36.862 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe5bf00a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-09-17 10:25:36.872 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5bf00a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf0da9bd0)
2019-09-17 10:25:36.903 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2019-09-17 10:25:36.925 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5bf00a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf0da9bd0)
2019-09-17 10:25:36.947 13305-13336/com.myname.myapp D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
```

Edit 2: There is a new error message now that might help:

```
    2019-09-17 13:28:13.400 1669-2304/? E/ActivityManager: Second failure launching com.myname.myapp/.MainActivity, giving up
        android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 520984 bytes
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:748)
            at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(IApplicationThread.java:1230)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1467)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:972)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:6958)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:7025)
            at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:291)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2935)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
    2019-09-17 13:28:13.434 1669-1690/? E/ViewRootImpl[myapp]: Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
          window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@da270ff, title=Splash Screen com.myname.myapp
```

Comment: Can you post the log? So we can see it there's any exception

Comment: I added the log, thanks.

Comment: Try to add MultiDex.install(base) in your application class

Comment: Like this?

@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

Same results.

Comment: In mainActivity getIntent() throw exception. bcoz your passing ArrayList. try to put in try-catch or check getIntent() not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it explains why the behavior changed although there were no changes in the code:

the string `strResult` grew bigger than the maximum length that can be put into the `Intent` using `putStringArrayListExtra` as the database grew over time. In my case I could simply reduce the amount of data, which obviously cannot be a solution in every case. All other suggested changes in code lead to a better style, so thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You've not shared the Logcat error stack, it would've helped to further understand the issue. But it seems you are trying to start the activity from a new thread and not the UI thread, because of which the app is crashing, just move out the code inside runnable run method, and don't start a new thread. If for some reason you want the code to run asynchronously, run your Runnable through a handler. Below is the snippet

```
if (isOnline()) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_users), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
            strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_ridesByDate), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
            strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_ridesByDriverID), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
            strResult.add(new DataTransfer().receiveDataFromDatabase(getString(R.string.sql_id_passengersByDate), "0", getString(R.string.url_receive), getmAccessCode()));
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("tableContents", strResult);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    },1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I added the log to the original post now. I tested your suggestions, I'm afraid it doesn't make a difference. I guess I'll keep the changes though, it's probably stil better than my original version.

Comment: I was wrong, with your code the SplashScreen doesn't show anymore and the app crashes even earlier. So I have to keep my version.

Comment: there is one more thing, when you are passing an arraList in the intent use i.putStringArrayListExtra("tableContents", strResult) instead of i.putExtra("tableContents", strResult)

Comment: if you want to show the SplashScreen and move to MainActivity after some delay you can use Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, delay in miliseconds) instead of Hanlder.post()

Comment: That works as expected, it doesn't solve the general problem though. Should I edit the original post and change to splash screen code to the new version?

Comment: There is a new error message now, I added it to the original post.